# Is JavaScript standby functionality stored in RAM or the hard drive?

Tags: javascript, v8

This is a bit of a strange question where I do not know enough to possibly ask it correctly, so I will do my best (googling for a worthwhile result has proven difficult):

- You write a Javascript program
- V8 (or other interpreters) compiles your script (I understand WHICH interpreter is running vastly changes the results of the answer to this, so let's stick with V8)
- Your Javascript could be a formidably large footprint of executable code
- Does V8 keep any routines that are not in use on the hard drive? Or does the Javascript interpreted commands stay completely in RAM?

I was wondering this because it would seem unfortunate for a massive JS program to eat into the available RAM allotment a browser gives if the complexity of the JS program was overtly large.

I know this gets into: if you have such a huge program you're doing it wrong, but I like to push things where I can and if I get a better understanding of how this all works, I can make better decisions :)

Comment: Define `not in use`. Does it mean that the function hasn't been called yet or that there are no references to it? Or perhaps there are references to it but never called?

Comment: My answer below assumes "not in use" means "previously called but not right now". If it's never been called, then V8 wouldn't even have compiled it; if there are no references to it anymore, it would get garbage-collected. That said, I agree that even if an engine wanted to push "unused" things to disk, it would be very difficult to decide what counts as "unused" -- you'd really want to know what *will not be used* any time soon, but predicting the future is notoriously difficult ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(V8 developer here.) Short answer: no, V8 does not swap any unused things (code or otherwise) to disk at runtime.

Executable code is typically not the biggest consumer of memory we see in V8, it tends to be dwarfed by (non-code) data. Still, the amount of code can certainly be significant; one of the reasons why V8 switched its first (unoptimized) execution tier from a compiler to an interpreter a few years ago was because that interpreter's bytecode is much smaller than the earlier non-optimizing compiler's machine code it replaced. When a function is optimized, it's still compiled to machine code; but since typically only relatively few functions get optimized, that usually only takes up a low single-digit percentage of overall memory.

In embedders that support it (like Chrome), V8 does support caching certain things between runs, including code. That's a performance optimization: some work can be avoided if you visit the same website multiple times. This mechanism doesn't temporarily free up any memory, and it's not supposed to.

Generally, it's not the job of individual applications to swap things to disk -- it's the job of the operating system. When all running applications combined use more memory than is available, then the kernel will pick some "pages" (chunks of memory) and write them to disk. Applications don't notice any of that (except a massive loss of performance when those pages are needed again) and don't have to do any work to support it. So this part of the answer applies not just to V8, but also to other JavaScript engines, and in general to all other programs you may run on your computer.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent breakdown. I'll investigate it from this angle in understanding that the interpreter makes it an OS issue. Definitely plenty to branch off of in understanding it all better :)